# Fast input method of number in c/c++?

Tags: c++

```
inline int input()
{
    int c;        
    int n = 0;

    while ((c = getchar_unlocked()) >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        // n = 10 * n + (c - '0');
        n = (n << 3) + ( n << 1 ) + c - '0';
    }
    return n;
}
```

Can someone explain how this way of inputting the number is working and how it is the fast way to input a number?

Comment: @KerrekSB: completely missing the micro optimization opportunity to get rid of the two compares in the loop...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compilers are generally very stupid, and have no understanding of the logic you're trying to implement. Moreover, they're often written by less-than-competent people who don't understand much of modern hardware.

The author of the code has realized this, and cleverly analyzed that 10 is the same as 8 + 2, and that 8 and 2 are both powers of two. For the flourish, he proceeded to turn the mathematics of exponentials into native, bitwise hardware instructions. This combination of mathematics and deep understanding of the hardware leads him to factor `10 * x` as `8 * x + 2 * x` and express the result in terms of instructions that are far more optimal than the naive "stupid multiplication" that would otherwise have taken place. Naturally, such optimizations are far beyond the reach of any kind of technology and cannot possibly be performed automatically.

The result is a vastly improved method of multiplying a number by ten.

Patent pending.

Comment: I honestly don't know in which direction to vote...

Comment: Please note that this method can be extended to arbitrary integers.

Comment: @KerrekSB: only have one mouse :(

Comment: @phimuemue: Do that and I'll sue your ass off.

Comment: [Note: this post may be ironic. It is *possible* that your compiler and/or hardware *are* in fact aware of efficient ways of performing multiplication. Consult your vendor, and/or benchmark.]

Comment: +1 I like it, even though you only explained "how it is the fast way". For the "how it is working", let's add some nice uppercase sigma and pi symbols for discussion of [Horner's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). I think it was called.

Comment: You forgot to talk about the huge improvement in readability ! Who would understand `10*n` ? No-bo-dy ! Whereas `(n << 3) + ( n << 1 )` is so obvious that my cat answered me when I asked her if it was clear.

Answer (score 1):

`n << 3` equals `n * 8`
`n << 1` equals `n * 2`

i.e. `(n << 3) + ( n << 1 )` equals `10 * n`

bitwise shift is faster than multiplication, though I'm not sure the whole thing should be faster.

Comment: While it's true that bitwise shift is faster than multiplication at the hardware level, it's not necessarily true that `n << 3` is faster than `n * 8`. Compiler writers know how to do this kind of thing.